# NodeJS PUT request returns error 400 (Bad Request)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I am trying to do a PUT request with NodeJS, Express and MongoDB. The issue that I am currently having is that I keep receiving an `error **400**` and I am not sure exactly why.

What I am exactly trying to do is upload edit a **field** in my **USER** collection, after a certain user has been registered. This is supposed to happen on a specific `/user/edit/:id` route.

My application is structured with a standard MVC pattern.

Here is how my `Mongo Schema` is structured:

```
let UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  username: String,
  password: String,
  email: String,
  avatar: String,
  firstName: String,
  lastName: String,
  laps:[{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Stats' }]
});
```

This is my service:

```
exports.updateUser = async function(user) {
  let id = user.id;
  let oldUser;
  try {
    //Find the old User Object by the Id
    oldUser = await User.findById(id);
  } catch(e) {
    throw Error("Error occured while Finding the User");
  }
  // If no old User Object exists return false
  if (!oldUser) {
    return false;
  }
  //Edit the User Object
  oldUser.firstName = user.firstName || oldUser.firstName;
  oldUser.lastName = user.lastName || oldUser.lastName;
  oldUser.avatar = user.avatar || oldUser.avatar;
  try {
    let savedUser = await oldUser.save();
    return savedUser;
  } catch(e) {
    throw Error("And Error occured while updating the User");
  }
};
```

The Controller that I am using:

```
exports.updateUser = async function(req, res, next) {
  if (!req.body._id){
    return res.status(400).json({status: 400, message: "Id must be present"})
  }
  let id = req.body._id;
  let user = {
    id,
    firstName: req.body.firstName || null,
    lastName: req.body.lastName || null,
    avatar: req.body.avatar || null
  };
  try {
    let updatedUser = await UserService.updateUser(user);
    return res.status(200).json({status: 200, data: updatedUser, message: "Successfully Updated User"})
  } catch(e) {
    return res.status(400).json({status: 400, message: e.message})
  }
};
```

Route path in router file:

```
router.post('/edit/:id', UserController.updateUser);
```

Route path for users inside server file:

```
app.use('/user', require('./api/routes/user.route'));
```

I know that most `4**` errors come from the front end of the application, so I will also post my form and the constructor behind it. I am using ReactJS as a framework.

Front end Form:

```
class UserProfile extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      avatar: '',
      resultsSubmitted: false
    };
    this.formChange = this.formChange.bind(this);
    this.resultsSubmit = this.resultsSubmit.bind(this);
  }
  formChange(e) {
    console.log("form changed" + e.target);
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    this.setState({ [name]: value });
  }
  resultsSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const accessToken = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('auth_user')).data.access_token;
    const { avatar } = this.state;
    const { dispatch } = this.props;
    if (avatar) {
      console.log("submitting results: " + avatar);
      dispatch(userActions.addAvatar(avatar, accessToken));
    }
  }
  render(){
      const { avatar, resultsSubmitted} = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="container-fluid no-gutters page-login">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="login-wrapper">
            <h2> Edit User Profile </h2>

            <form onSubmit={this.resultsSubmit}>
              <div className="form-group">
                Paste Avatar URL: <input type="text" value={avatar} name="avatar" id="" onChange={this.formChange} />
              </div>
              <input type="submit" className="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" value="submit"/>
            </form>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  const { layout } = state;
  return {
    layout
  };
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(UserProfile);
```

My dispatch:

```
function addAvatar(avatar, token) {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch(request());
    userService.addAvatar(avatar, token)
      .then(
        user => {
          dispatch(success(user));
          history.push(`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/`);
        },
        error => {
          dispatch(failure(error));
          dispatch(alertActions.error(error));
        }
      );
  };
  function request() { return { type: userConstants.AVATAR_REQUEST } }
  function success(user) { return { type: userConstants.AVATAR_SUCCESS, user } }
  function failure(error) { return { type: userConstants.AVATAR_FAILURE, error } }
}
```

HTTP Post service:

```
function addAvatar(avatar){
  const requestOptions = {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: authHeader(),
    body:  avatar
  };
  return fetch('http://localhost:3003/user/edit/:id', requestOptions)
    .then(response => {
      if (!response.ok) {
        console.log("+",response,"+");
        return Promise.reject(response.statusText);
      }else{
        console.log(response, "the user service response was gooooooooooood");
      }
      return response.json();
    })
    .then(data => console.log(data,"WHT DO WE HAVE HERE?"));
}
```

Apologies for the huge code wall but I wanted to include all the bits.

> I am getting an error 400 (Bad Request) on the route POST
>   `http://localhost:3003/user/edit/:id`

Comment: What error do you get in the Network tab of the Developer Tools? It might be a CORS issue.

Comment: I'm thinking it might be because the `id` field does not have a key in the user JSON object you're creating. Could you try changing it to `id: id` and see if it helps?

Answer (score 2):

In your fetch request you are sending only avatar as a body and on your updateUser function you have the following if statement:

```
if (!req.body._id){
    return res.status(400).json({status: 400, message: "Id must be present"})
}
```

so obviously you have not _id on your body request but an avatar instead, in fact you're sending your id as a param

```
'http://localhost:3003/user/edit/:id'
```

So you could change this line as a  workaround

```
if (!req.params.id){
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: yes but I am receiving null as an input from somewhere

Answer (score 1):

The below snippet shows that you are trying to get the ID parameter from the body of the request.

```
if (!req.body._id){
    return res.status(400).json({status: 400, message: "Id must be present"})
}
```

**Whereas**, the route `/user/edit/:id` , shows that the ID parameter is actually passed through the URL, and to access it, all you need is to get your ID from the URL using `req.params.id`. `req.params` contains all parameters that are passed through the route or URL path.

The above snippet should be corrected to;

```
if (!req.params.id){
    return res.status(400).json({status: 400, message: "Id must be present"})
}
```

Check https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html#route-parameters for proper guide on how to deal with route parameter.